# Log Parser SQL Connection String

Tags: logparser

Im am currently attempting to use log parser to import some data from windows event logs. I've run the command through on my local machine and sql instance but when I attempt to run on the live server it errors.

The issue seems to be related to the server name as i get a connection string error. My machine is named FF-IT05, but the live server is Omega/Reports. I've tried wrapping the server string  in {} and []  (and nothing at all) but it still erros.

Does anyone know the syntax for the above server string??

Comment: Can you share the full error message that you get? Also, are you running this from a script or manually from the command line?

Comment: Managed to find a solution to it, thank you for responding though.